# Can I substitute teriyaki glaze and baste for teriyaki sauce?

Tags: substitutions

I have some [teriyaki glaze and baste](http://www.kikkomanusa.com/homecooks/products/products_hc_details.php?pf=10204&fam=102), but my recipe calls for teriyaki sauce. Can I use this and just add some soy sauce to it to "water" it down. Currently it is the consistency of ketchup, but it should be like soy sauce, a liquid.

I guess my question is, can I turn teriyaki glaze and baste back into teriyaki sauce?

Answer (score 1):

Well I just tried it and added some soy sauce and brown sugar. It tasted pretty close.

Comment: I'd have actually used water rather than soy for fear of making it too salty.

Comment: That's a good idea, I had to add extra brown sugar to keep it from getting too salty.

Comment: To improve your answer a bit, do you want to include the ratio added?

Comment: I'll have to experiment to figure it out, I just added some till it tasted good.